# What is the process of creating a link that will expire using a specific key?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I am implementing a password reset function and would have the key I want to use as a parameter to a jsp page(I assume that is how it's done. How can I pass parameters and to the jsp page and make those parameters only active for a certain amount of time?

Comment: Well what your looking for is typically called token based authentication, however your implementation of it depends on the structure of your application. Are you already using a library to manage users/passwords?

Comment: I am adding a feature onto an application that is being developed and we have written our own sql for users/passwords and such. I just need to know how to expire links and pass parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *how can I pass parameters and to the jsp page*

Just include it in request URL.

> http://example.com/activate.jsf?key=12345678

---

> *and make those parameters only active for a certain amount of time that*

Store a timestamp along the key in the DB when the key is generated for the first time. Retrieve the timestamp from the DB when the key is requested. If the difference with the current time is too big, invalidate it. Don't forget to setup a background job to cleanup keys which are never used within a too long time, otherwise the DB may grow out its borders with unused keys.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I'm not sure what project you have there, but if you can, upgrade to JSF 2.x with Facelets as soon as possible. JSP is only typical for old JSF 1.x and is deprecated since JSF 2.0 almost 2.5 years ago.

Comment: I think we are planning on writing some sort of cron job to do this every now and then. Our user base isn't that large so I am thinking weekly would be enough. Thanks for your answer can you elaborate a little on what you mean by invalidate it?

Comment: Uh, just don't treat it as valid. Don't activate the user associated with the key. Remove the key from the DB and show a friendly error message that the key is invalid and that the enduser can generate a new key by [link]. Makes sense, right?

Comment: Yes thanks. And on the unrelated note we are using the latest jsf framework just within .jsp file is that not correct?

Comment: JSP is deprecated. It's succeeded by Facelets which offers enormous advantages such as templating support, ajax support, composite component support, etc. See also http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html

Comment: Okay thanks for the heads up. As you can tell I am a noob :). Thanks a lot for your help.